# Get file path of R script

Tags: r

I would like to get the file path of the R script that I am running.  eg

when I run the function it will return

"C:/Users/Forename.Surname/Documents/foo.R"

(I am running Rstudio)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `getSrcDirectory()` function. For example, if you put this in a file:

```
scriptPath <- function() {
    getSrcDirectory(scriptPath);
}
```

Then calling `scriptPath()` from will tell you where the script file is located.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  unfortuntely that is just returning ""

Comment: Make sure it's in a file that's saved and sourced.